# Remove Ubuntu completely from my computer and install windows

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, boot, grub, uninstall

I installed Ubuntu in my machine after formatting my computer. It is now difficult to remove and restore my Windows.
The problem is that I can't boot from my Windows CD. I select the option to <strike>burn</strike> boot from CD but it goes on to Ubuntu. 
I have formatted the hard disk with another computer and now there is an error of grub rescue, whatever it is.
Still my computer cannot see the windows CD.
What can I do ?

Comment: Not sure why your disc isn't being read, but if your optical drive isn't working, you can install Windows with a flash drive too. Step by step instructions here: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/9585/how-to-setup-a-usb-flash-drive-to-install-windows-7/

Comment: ok can you please try to be a bit more precise, do you have windows still install ? Do you know how to select boot order so CD will be chosen first ? what do you try so far ==>Precisely<==

Comment: Its difficult to precisely understand the current scenario. Please add some more details...

Comment: Try the Ubuntu install disk again.  If you can boot from your Ubuntu disk, then the error is with the windows install disk.  If you can't boot from your Ubuntu disk, then the error is with the cd drive.

Answer (score 2):

First ensure your computer is booting from a CD by using F8, DEL or whatever key it tells you to enter Boot Options and set CD Drive as first boot priority. (Since you have Ubuntu you have probably done this, but we need to check).

If it still doesn't see it then try burning another disc to ensure you have a working copy of your Windows system on disc. Test it in another computer if needs be.

Finally ensure the CD Drive in the computer does actually work. Once again try it in another computer or using a disc you know works.

If, by change, you are actually seeing the Boot from CD option while the system is loading (but it won't do anything) ensure you are using a PS/2 keyboard rather than USB. Linux can be temperamental with this

Give this lot a try and let us know the result